# My real first and last name is showing up when I get killed or get a kill on Steam

Tags: steam, fistful-of-frags

Not that it matters too much because I don’t have social media, but I’d rather my name not be public. I don't know why but every time I get killed in a game or I do the killing, it says my full name. Weirdest thing I’ve ever dealt with, but I’m new to pc.

Comment: Just to make sure: is your Steam username different from your real name?

Comment: The killfeed shows your Steam profile name. You can change it the Steam settings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Steam profile settings, maybe?

https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4113-YUDH-6401

> 1. From your Steam Profile, click the Edit Profile link under your displayed badge.
> 2. Click the My Privacy Settings tab
> 3. Select your privacy state
> 4. Click the Save button